# Clear messages in QgsMessageBar of QgsPluginManagerInterface

Tags: pyqgis, plugins, interface

`QgsPluginManagerInterface` has a `pushMessage` method to send messages to its `QgsMessageBar`. But there is no similar function as `QgisInterface.messageBar` with `clearWidgets` in it. How can I clear the messages in the message bar of `QgsPluginManagerInterface` ? I checked the children of it but it returns an empty list.